Census API Error Message: ACS Subject Tables for Zip Codes (ambiguous geography)
Have you seen the following error:
Getting data from the 2014-2018 5-year ACS
Using the ACS Subject Tables
Error: Your API call has errors.  The API message returned is error: ambiguous geography "zip code tabulation area:93901,93905,93906,93908,93926,93927,93930,93933,93940,93943,93944,93955,93960,95012,95076". You must either specify a wildcard or full qualify it with state.
Data2018 <- get_acs(
  geography ="zcta",
  variables = var_list,
  year = 2018,
  zcta = c("93901",
           "93905",
           "93906",
           "93908",
           "93926",
           "93927",
           "93930",
           "93933",
           "93940",
           "93943",
           "93944",
           "93955",
           "93960",
           "95012",
           "95076"),
  moe_level = 95
)

This works for more recent years: 2022 to 2019.

As the error message states, if you specify a state, e.g., state="CA", this runs smoothly.

Thanks, Cristian, I also figured it out. Do you know why I would need to do that for 2018 but not more recent years?

Hard to say without diving deep into the American Community Survey Census API documentation. Based on different example API calls from 2018 and 2022, I suspect newer years simply did away with the requirement to specify state, e.g., 2018 ACS must specify &for=zip%20code%20tabulation%20area:00610&in=state:72 in the request for a single ZCTA, whereas 2022 ACS only specifies the ZCTA without the state in the for clause.

I figured it out. For 2018 (and after), you have to specify the state:
#grab zip code variables for one year
Data2018 <- get_acs(
  geography ="zcta",
  variables = var_list,
  year = 2018,
  state = "06",
  zcta = c("93901",
           "93905",
           "93906",
           "93908",
           "93926",
           "93927",
           "93930",
           "93933",
           "93940",
           "93943",
           "93944",
           "93955",
           "93960",
           "95012",
           "95076"),
  moe_level = 95
)


In this case, 06 = California
